# How to declare a std::map from EnumType to EnumTypeValue?

Tags: c++, dictionary, templates, enums

I have an enum:

```
enum VehicleType {CAR, BIKE, TRUCK};
```

The following class uses this enum as a template parameter:

```
template <VehicleType V>
class ParkingSlotContainer
{
    ...
};
```

Now, I wish to define a class with a map data member that maps a `VehicleType` to `ParkingSlotContainer<VehicleType>`. In other words, I want to map `CAR` to `ParkingSlotContainer<CAR>`, `BIKE` to `ParkingSlotContainer<BIKE>`, etc.

This is my attempt:

```
class ParkingFloor
{
private:
    int floor;
    map<VehicleType, ParkingSlotContainer<VehicleType> > slots;
public:
    ParkingFloor(...);
    ...
};
```

The compiler doesn't accept the above and reports that `type name is not allowed`. It expects `ParkingSlotContainer<CAR|BIKE|TRUCK>` instead of `ParkingSlotContainer<VehicleType>`.

What is the right way to define such a map?

Comment: One common work-around is to have a non-template base class (possibly polymorphic), and then use (smart) pointers to the base class as the data. Create objects dynamically and store the pointer. Downcast if needed.

Comment: You can't. Thing is that ParkingSlotContainer<CAR> and ParkingSlotContainer<BIKE> and ParkingSlotContainer<TRUCK> are *completely different classes*. You might consider simply writing `ParkingSlotContainer<CAR> carslot; ParkingSlotContainer<BIKE> bikeslot; ParkingSlotContainer<TRUCK> truckslot;`

Comment: By the way, in this case I don't really see the need for a map. Why not simply an array with three elements? Possibly pointers as describe in my previous comment. Or three distinct variables as described by @user253751?

Comment: The thing with an array or map is that even if you could do it, then because each entry is a completely separate class, what could you even do with the array? You couldn't write `array[index].doSomething();` because the compiler wouldn't know which class `array[index]` was because all of them would be different.

Comment: `ParkingSlotContainer<VehicleType>` is not a type, nor is `ParkingSlotContainer`. The first is a hard error, and the second is a template.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Three distinct variables is definitely possible, but I wanted a better solution in which I don't need to touch the classes if I add an extra value in the enum later on.

Comment: @mrpandey Can you explain why ParkingSlotContainer needs to be a template with VehicleType known at compile-time?

Comment: @Rulle I wanted to enforce that a ParkingSlotContainer instance only contains vehicles having a particular VehicleType.

Comment: @mrpandey Then you should include the code for the body of the ParkingSlotContainer and code that shows how you are using ParkingFloor. And code for the vehicles that you store in the containers. Because right now, this is all pretty unclear...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot have two values of different type in an `std::map`: For instance, you cannot have both a `ParkingSlotContainer<BIKE>` and `ParkingSlotContainer<CAR>` inside the `slots` variable, because they are different types.

For these kinds of situations where you want to produce types from enum values, you may want to use [higher order macros](https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2012/01/24/higher-order-macros-in-c/). Here is an example of higher order macros applied to your code, where we use them to declare three member variables (`_CAR`, `_BIKE` and `_TRUCK`) for the three enum values and then generate overloaded methods `setSlot` to set a new value to any one of them. Just to demonstrate how you can use higher order macros:

```
#define FOREACH_VEHICLE_TYPE(OP) \
  OP(CAR) \
  OP(BIKE) \
  OP(TRUCK)

enum VehicleType {
  #define DECL_VEHICLE(name) name,
  FOREACH_VEHICLE_TYPE(DECL_VEHICLE)
  #undef DECL_VEHICLE
};

template <VehicleType V>
class ParkingSlotContainer
{
public:
  int vehicleCount = 0;
};

class ParkingFloor
{
private:
  int floor;
  
#define DECL_SLOT(name) ParkingSlotContainer<name> _##name;
FOREACH_VEHICLE_TYPE(DECL_SLOT)
#undef DECL_SLOT

public:
#define SET_SLOT(name) void setSlot(const ParkingSlotContainer<name>& newValue) {_##name = newValue;}
  FOREACH_VEHICLE_TYPE(SET_SLOT)
#undef SET_SLOT
};

int main() {
  ParkingSlotContainer<BIKE> bikes;
  bikes.vehicleCount = 119;

  ParkingFloor parkingFloor;
  parkingFloor.setSlot(bikes);
  return 0;
}
```

Depending on your application, this may or may not be overkill. It sort of makes the code harder to read...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But yes, macros make it harder to read.